# Usage of the word 'TOGGLE'

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The word 'toggle' itslef means switching between two states. But is it proper to use explicitly like 'toggle ON' or 'toggle OFF' ? How the usage for that word should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "toggle on" is okay, if you are using a toggle switch, or a toggle form control on a web page.

If you are talking about "activating something" then "turn on" is more common. "Toggle the switch to the 'on' position" is longer but explicit.